# Is my insert method in a Binary Search Tree Class which handles duplicate values incorrectly putting the elements in? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates, binary-tree, insertion

```
def insert(self, value) :
        self._total += int(value)
        
        if self.isEmpty() :
            self._root = self._Node(value)
            self._totalNums += 1
            self._distinctNums += 1
            return
        
        parent = None
        probe = self._root
        
        while (probe != None) :
            if value == probe._value:
                probe._count += 1
                self._totalNums += 1
                return
                
            if value < probe._value :
                parent = probe
                probe = probe._left
                
            else :
                parent = probe
                probe = probe._right
                
        
        if (value < parent._value) :
            parent._left = self._Node(value)
            self._totalNums += 1
            self._distinctNums += 1
        elif (value > parent._value) :
            parent._right = self._Node(value)
            self._totalNums += 1
            self._distinctNums += 1
```

When printing out the BST using an inorder traversal I get this:
(first is the element/value, c is the number of values, d is the depth of the value)

Printing the tree
1 c(4) d(1),
100 c(1) d(6),
1000 c(1) d(5),
2000 c(1) d(2),
23 c(1) d(1),
4 c(11) d(3),
45 c(2) d(1),
50 c(2) d(4),
67 c(1) d(1),

Comment: It isn't clear what the issue is here. Please specify. Also, it would be helpful if you put print statements in your code along with sample data which shows the issue. This is just a function which doesn't do anything if you run it. It is also possible that in doing the above suggestions, you will figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out, When comparing the values and probe._value, it was comparing the strings so it thought that "50" was greater than "100". Converting them to integers solved the problem